# Where is the URL Package?

Tags: emacs

> [The URL package contains code to parse and handle URLs. It was originally part of w3, the web browser written entirely in EmacsLisp. **Now it is a separate library available in Emacs 22.**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UrlPackage)

I am running Emacs 23.4.1 on my local Ubuntu machine and 24.3.1 on my FreeBSD development server. I am trying to decode a URL I pasted into a buffer by using <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `url-unhex-string`, but neither version of emacs has this, or ANY function mentioned in [that Emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UrlPackage).

While I don't have administrative access to the server, I do to my local machine. Is there a package I'm missing that I can get through Synaptic or something, or a configuration option/variable that needs to be changed? Even the [gnu.org page for the Url package says it should be included with emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/url/).